# Questions regarding object reference type casting in C#?

Tags: c#, object, types, reference, casting

I have a question regarding Object type casting.
Suppose we have:

```
A a = new A();
Object o = a;
```

As I know, what happens behind is that the compiler will copy the address of a and store in the memory area of o variable. Then,we can say that a and o are referencing to the same object.

If we do something like this:

```
String s = "abc";
int a = (int)s;
```

Then I understand that the compiler cannot copy the string value to the int memory area.

But if we have:

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;
```

This might be ok at the compile time. However, a run time error may happen which is something like "cannot casting....".

So, I dont understand what actually happen in memory that makes the above casting cannot be performed. Is it just copying the address of a to the memory area of b? If so, why it is not possible?
Or it will copy all the members of A to replace all the members of B?

Thanks

Comment: It's helpful when learning a managed language like C# to, at least in the beginning, forget the idea of objects taking up space in memory and copying memory from one place to another.  This is mostly irrelevant to the object-oriented abstraction and distracts from the concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler does *Static Type Checking* meaning that if A and B do not belong to the same inheritance hierarchy, it would not allow a cast to happen between the two. 

Think about it, if they are not belong to the same hierarchy, even if compiler lets you cast an object of A to a type of B, since A does not inherit from B or its inheritors, you might want to invoke one of the methods of type B on the casted object and it will fail miserably at runtime.

```
class A { }
class B { 
    void Foo() { }
}

A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;      // Compiler Error

// Hypothetically, if above was allowed, the below would ALWAYS fail at runtime
// Since there is no way the object "b" can handle this call.
b.Foo();
```

There is an interesting point exist here though, if B is an interface, the compiler would let the cast to happen even if they do not belong to the same inheritance tree:

```
class A { }
interface B { 
    void Foo();
}

A a = new A();
B b = (B)a;      // Compiler lets this happens 

// Even though A does not implement B, but still one of the base classes of A 
// might have implement B and A inherits that so it might be able to handle this
b.Foo();
```

The reason for that is because A might be from a different hierarchy tree but there is still possible that A or one of its Base classes have implemented B so you might have a point by that cast and compiler would let that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Everything is quite clear for me now. I have one more question. if Class A : B,then we can do the cast as follows: A a = (B)b;. What actually this does in memory? It will copy address of B and store in a variable?

Comment: No problem. Yes, then "a" will be refer to the object refers by "b" (i.e. the memory value of b variable will be copied into "a" variable which is merely an address in Heap-where the objects live).

Answer (score 0):

As Morteza explained, the C# compiler will do static type checking to determine if the cast is even possible.

As to what happens at runtime, you may want to take a look at the IL generated to get a better idea. For reference types, your cast will probably become the IL `castclass` instruction. This results in the runtime checking the actual object type to see if the cast is valid. If yes, the reference (a 32-bit or 64-bit pointer to your object) is imply copied in the variable assignment as you expected. If no, an InvalidCastException is thrown.

For reference type objects, the individual members are never copied. Only the 32/64-bit reference is copied. For value type objects, the individual members (fields) *are* copied during assignment.

Comment: "For reference type objects, the individual members are never copied. Only the 32/64-bit reference is copied. For value type objects, the individual members (fields) are copied during assignment." => what do you mean by that? I really do not understand. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: When a reference type is instantiated, the in-memory object layout (fields, vtable, etc.) is allocated on the managed heap. Any variables you assign to it are actually references (32/64-bit pointers to the heap address of object).

Comment: When a value type (anything deriving from System.Value or any C# "struct") is instantiated, the variable it's assigned to is the in-memory object layout (all the fields). There's no indirection like with reference types. And so when you assign another variable to the first variable, all fields are copied because each is its own in-memory object layout.

Comment: For example, if you have a reference type class A { int v1; int v2; int v3 } and do "A a1 = new A();" a new object consisting of 12 bytes (plus overhead) will be placed on the heap at say, address 0x1234. The variable a1 will have the 32/64-bit value 0x1234 which is a reference to the object. If you then do "A a2 = a1", the variable a2 will have the 32/64-bit value 0x1234. There's still only one object and both a1 and a2 reference it.

Comment: If you have a value type struct B { int v1; int v2; int v3; } and do "B b1 = new B();" the variable b1 will consist of the 12-bytes representing the 3 integer fields. if you then do "B b2 = b1;" the variable b2 will consist of 12-bytes that are a copy of b1. But if you do "b2.v1 = 43", it will not affect b1.v1 which will still have its default value of zero.